# Php Loop in bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I please need an explanation on how to express a loop in a manner that it collapses the bootstrap using a counter and a foreach loop but it looks like i am not getting the right response as i want it.

```
<?php
$views = ['First View','Second View','Third View'];
$messages = [
                "FIRST MESSAGE Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad",
                "SECOND MESSAGE Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad",
                "THIRD MESSAGE Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad",
            ];
?>

<section>

 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"><div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php 

    foreach($views as $view):  $count = 1;?>

        <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading<?php echo $count; ?>">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="<?php echo ($count == 1 ? '' : 'collapse'); ?>" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $count; ?>" aria-expanded="<?php echo ($count == 1 ? 'true' : 'false'); ?>" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $count; ?>">
              <?php echo strtoupper(" $view "); ?>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse<?php echo $count; ?>" class="panel-collapse <?php echo ($count == 1 ? 'collapse in' : 'collapse'); ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $count; ?>">

          <div class="panel-body">

            <?php foreach($messages as $message): ?>
                <?php echo "$count, $message";  ?>
            <?php endforeach;  ?>

          </div> <!-- end body -->

        </div>

      </div> <!-- end default -->



<?php  $count++; endforeach; ?>
</div> <!-- end 12 -->
</div> <!-- end accordion -->   
</div> <!-- END OF ROW
 -->

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your loop you're setting `$count = 1;` which means that count will ALWAYS be 1.

I'm assuming you want that var to increment to count your loops. Put it outside the loop and add 1 to it inside the loop.

```
$count = 1;
foreach($whatever as $something):
    // do stuff
    $count++;
endforeach;
```

Comment: It seems not to work, have a try at it and see what you get.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because you have 2 foreach loops and you're only closing one of them. ps "it doesn't work" is not helpful debugging information. include details. and you're getting free tech support don't expect people to take the time to copy your code into their own servers unless you're going to pay me my $30/hr rate.

Comment: nevermind, just saw the close for the other foreach. if you want to add something more helpful than "it doesn't work" then i'll be happy to take a second look.